# Yii with sqlite 3

Tags: sql, model, yii

in config folder in both console.php and main.php

i am using:

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:protected/data/qdr.sqlite',
),
```

the sqlite db is in data folder.

now when i am trying to create model users (there is a table named users)

with the command 
yiic shell
model users

it is showing the error:

```
>> model users
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB conne
ction: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in F:\wamp\www\qdr\fra
mework\db\CDbConnection.php:381
Stack trace:
#0 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive
(true)
#2 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(438): CModule->getComponent('
db')
#4 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\shell\ModelCommand.php(259): CApplicat
ion->getDb()
#5 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(128): ModelCommand->r
un(Array)
#6 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(99): ShellCommand->ru
nShell()
#7 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleCommandRunner.php(67): ShellCommand
->run(Array)
#8 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleApplication.php(91): CConsoleComman
dRunner->run(Array)
#9 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(169): CConsoleApplication->pr
ocessRequest()
#10 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#11 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic(14): require_once('F:\wamp\www\qdr...')
#12 {main}
>> model users
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB conne
ction: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in F:\wamp\www\qdr\fra
mework\db\CDbConnection.php:381
Stack trace:
#0 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive
(true)
#2 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(438): CModule->getComponent('
db')
#4 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\shell\ModelCommand.php(259): CApplicat
ion->getDb()
#5 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(128): ModelCommand->r
un(Array)
#6 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(99): ShellCommand->ru
nShell()
#7 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleCommandRunner.php(67): ShellCommand
->run(Array)
#8 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleApplication.php(91): CConsoleComman
dRunner->run(Array)
#9 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(169): CConsoleApplication->pr
ocessRequest()
#10 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#11 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic(14): require_once('F:\wamp\www\qdr...')
#12 {main}
>> model users
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB conne
ction: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in F:\wamp\www\qdr\fra
mework\db\CDbConnection.php:381
Stack trace:
#0 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive
(true)
#2 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(438): CModule->getComponent('
db')
#4 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\shell\ModelCommand.php(259): CApplicat
ion->getDb()
#5 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(128): ModelCommand->r
un(Array)
#6 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(99): ShellCommand->ru
nShell()
#7 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleCommandRunner.php(67): ShellCommand
->run(Array)
#8 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleApplication.php(91): CConsoleComman
dRunner->run(Array)
#9 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(169): CConsoleApplication->pr
ocessRequest()
#10 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#11 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic(14): require_once('F:\wamp\www\qdr...')
#12 {main}
>> model users > test.txt
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB conne
ction: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file' in F:\wamp\www\qdr\fra
mework\db\CDbConnection.php:381
Stack trace:
#0 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(330): CDbConnection->open()
#1 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\db\CDbConnection.php(308): CDbConnection->setActive
(true)
#2 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CModule.php(387): CDbConnection->init()
#3 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(438): CModule->getComponent('
db')
#4 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\shell\ModelCommand.php(259): CApplicat
ion->getDb()
#5 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(128): ModelCommand->r
un(Array)
#6 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\cli\commands\ShellCommand.php(99): ShellCommand->ru
nShell()
#7 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleCommandRunner.php(67): ShellCommand
->run(Array)
#8 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\console\CConsoleApplication.php(91): CConsoleComman
dRunner->run(Array)
#9 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\base\CApplication.php(169): CConsoleApplication->pr
ocessRequest()
#10 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic.php(33): CApplication->run()
#11 F:\wamp\www\qdr\framework\yiic(14): require_once('F:\wamp\www\qdr...')
#12 {main}
```

what to do, what wrong here?

Comment: how to connect to the database qdr.sqlite? I am having problem connecting with the database in sqlite within yii framework

Comment: i think there is problem with .sqlite file type, they are using .db for sqlite...!!!!?!?!

Comment: do you have sqlite module installed in php? check from `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Use 'connectionString'=>'sqlite:f:\wamp\www\qdr\protected\data\testdrive.db' in main.php It works ....ta-da..........

Comment: For anyone finding this issue with yii2, you can still use the above but it's better to use the app alias to make the app portable: `sqlite:@app/path/database.db`

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out. The problem is with the server. I reinstalled it at everything fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yii has two configuration files. Console configuration isnt the same of website configuration. Maybe you have not yet [set the right values in configuration files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#customizing-console-applications).